# Cannot cast class when using Google Analytics in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-analytics

I think I have all the elements right in my Eclipse projects but I still receive this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast
>   to cam.main.AnalyticsApplication

Here's the AnalyticsApplication code:

```
package cam.main;

public class AnalyticsApplication extends Application {

    private Tracker tracker;

    public AnalyticsApplication() {
        super();
    }

    synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
        if (tracker == null) {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            tracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.analytics);
        }
        return tracker;
    }
}
```

Here's the Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="cam.main"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="6"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/bot_img_1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity            android:name="cam.main.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <- other activities from the app ->

    </application>

    <application android:name="cam.main.AnalyticsApplication">
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And I have this code on the OnCreate method of my starting activity (StartMenu)

```
AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
Tracker mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
```

I don't know if it's important but I have AnalyticsApplication and StartMenu in the same file.

Is there a need to create an Activity inside the AnalyticsApplication or something?

Comment: Can you show extended cut of your AndroidManifest file? It's very strange to see 2 <application> tags in manifest. May be this is the key to your issue.

Comment: How do I declare the Analytics application then? I thought I needed to declare the Main app (the app I'm developing) and the Analytics application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include your `android:name="cam.main.AnalyticsApplication"` parameter to an exist application tag like this:

```
<application
    android:name="cam.main.AnalyticsApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/bot_img_1"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity            android:name="cam.main.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <- other activities from the app ->

</application>
```

Your custom Application class works incorrectly because of 2nd  tag.